# Stacking a listview on top of a textview Android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, textview

In my activity I need a ListView on top of my TextView.  How can I achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with an `ImageView` thanks to some help from folks on SO.  I created from my own class inheriting from `BaseAdapter` and then overrode the `getView` method of that class.  Basically, what you end up doing is shoving your own view, which in your case would be a `TextView` inside the `ListView` via the `getView` method.

You can reference my implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904529/baseadapter-in-listactivity-isnt-displaying-the-correct-items).

Comment: Note that both of the other answers provide a non-scrollable view above the `ListView`.  In my case I specifically did _not_ want this.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to have a listview and a textview,
Try giving android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_height="0px" for the listview and place the textview below the listview inside the same layout

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     <ListView android:layout_above="@id/text"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```